# link an XML document with an XSL-FO stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, xsl-fo

The linking of an XML document with an XSLT stylesheet can be done with:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foobar.xsl"?>
```

placed in the XML document.

How can I bind my XML document to an XSL-FO stylesheet? Is there something like that

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foobar.fo"?>
```

for the XSL-FO transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an XML file (test.xml) and want to transform it. To see the result of an XSLT stylesheet transformation I just need to link m< XML file test.xml to the stylesheet file foobar.xsl and open the XML file in a browser, that implements an XSLT processor. Now I'm trying the same approach for the XSL-FO transformation, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you can do a transformation in the browser using a stylesheet that outputs HTML, you can do it with a stylesheet that outputs XSL-FO. But that wouldn't be a meaningful thing to do, since web browsers do not understand XSL-FO markup.

To get rendered output (such as PDF) from XSL-FO, you need a FO processor. Regular web browsers do not come with a FO processor (for a possible exception, check out [X-Smiles](http://www.xsmiles.org/xsmiles_features.html#xslfo); not tested by me).

Comment: I thought, modern browsers would have a built-in FO processor (in the same manner like they provide XSLT processors). So, I need a special browser (X-Smiles) or an external [XSL-FO processor](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/FOprocessors.html). OK. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @automatix - Modern browsers don't even support XSLT 2.0; XSL-FO would be even further down the list.